# In Haskell, how do I turn an Integer into a Proxy (n :: KnownNat) with n equal to the integer?

Tags: haskell, vector, proxy

I'm trying to use the `slice'` function from `Data.Vector.Sized`, but it wants the *starting position* and *length* in `Proxy n` form, as opposed to simple `Integer`s. I know what both numbers are, in `Integer` form. How can I convert them to `Proxy n` form, to use this function?

Comment: This isn't possible, since you must know the size of the vectors at compile time. You can't just convert from an `Integer` to a proxy. To see why, imagine what the type of that function would be.

Comment: Isn't this what `someNatVal` is for? [Docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can’t. The meaning of a `KnownNat n` constraint is that `n` is a type-level natural number **with a value that’s known at compile-time**. An `Integer` represents an integer value that’s known at *runtime*, and it can be influenced by all sorts of factors that might not be known until runtime (such as user input, randomness, the state of the filesystem, accessing a database, reading from the file system, etc.).

The purpose of `Data.Vector.Sized` is to perform **compile-time** bounds checks, which of course can’t be done without knowing something about the size at compile-time. Once you have an `Integer`, you can’t magically convert it to a `Nat` because that would require divining at compile-time the value it will eventually have at runtime, when in fact it might not even always be the same value every time.

Depending on what you’re trying to do, there might be various ways to encode what you want. For example, you can use something like [`packFinite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/finite-typelits-0.1.3.0/docs/Data-Finite.html#v:packFinite) to produce some evidence at runtime that an integer is within a given range, and you can use [`knownLength`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized-1.0.4.0/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html#v:knownLength) to run a computation on a vector of unknown size, but neither of these really allow you to magic a `Nat` from an `Integer`, they merely convince they type system that you have performed the appropriate runtime checks in the case that your `Integer` actually falls outside the bounds you promised.